# JVM crashes and generates core file

Tags: jvm, jvm-crash

We keep getting JVM crashes in our production Linux environment almost everyday even when there isn't that much load on the server, here is snippet of core file below that we get every time there is a JVM crash
'

```html
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000f120, pid=0, tid=61700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_144-b01) (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.144-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x711120]  JNIHandleBlock::oops_do(OopClosure*)+0x30
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007fef2404e000):  ConcurrentGCThread [stack: 0x00062000,0x0000762000] [id=80133]

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), si_addr: 0x000

Registers:
RAX=0x00007fef2401eae0, RBX=0x0000000000000d14, RCX=0x00007fe468000000, RDX=0x0000000000000000
RSP=0x00007fef286609d0, RBP=0x00007fef28660a00, RSI=0x00000000746e7572, RDI=0x00007fef29994760
R8 =0x00007fef2401eae0, R9 =0x0000000000000018, R10=0x000018d500000000, R11=0x00007fef2404f730
R12=0x00000000000068a0, R13=0x00007fef29994760, R14=0x00007fef28660b20, R15=0x00007fef29994760
RIP=0x00007fef2b00f120, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010212, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00609d0)
0x00007fef286609d0:   00007fef28660b20 00007fef28660b20
0x00007fef286609e0:   00007fef28660b38 00007fe3d0769260
0x00007fef286609f0:   00007fe4c3dd24b8 00007fe3f7814048
0x00007fef28660a00:   00007fef28660a30 00007fef2ad69c90
0x00007fef28660a10:   00007fef24054c80 00007fe4c3dd24b8
0x00007fef28660a20:   00007fef24054c80 00007fef28660b20
0x00007fef28660a30:   00007fef28660a70 00007fef2af58930
0x00007fef28660a40:   0000000000000000 00007fe4c3dd24b8
0x00007fef28660a50:   00007fef24054c80 00007fef28660b70
```

Comment: 1. Update JRE (as you're using a *very* old version). 2. Send the complete crash log if the error persists.

Comment: Please upload the full core dump, it generally contains other useful info.